# why does Rust's Add trait take ownership?

Tags: rust

I am writing a toy BigInt class, and while I was implementing the [`Add trait`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html), I noticed that the it takes ownership of both sides. What problem is that trying to solve, as opposed to borrowing them by reference? Since I am using a `Vec` as the underlying data structure, I cannot implement `Copy`, and that makes it somewhat cumbersome to use.

An example of a (minor) inconvenience that it causes:

```rust
let i = BigInt::new();
//  - move occurs because `i` has type `BigInt`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
let j = i + 16u32;
//      --------- `i` moved due to usage in operator
let k = i + 32u32;
//      ^ value used here after move
```

Again, I know I can just use `.clone()`, but I am curious about in which ways this is helping the programmer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example of why it's important to be able to take ownership is so that `String + &str` can append to the existing string, instead of cloning it first.

You can always implement `Add` for references and `.clone`ing inside of them.

```rust
struct A;

impl std::ops::Add for A {
    // normal impl
}

impl<'a> std::ops::Add for &'a A {
    // clone and delegate
}


fn main() {
    A + A; // This still compiles
    &A + &A; // This now compiles
    &A + A; A + &A; // These won't compile, but you can add those impls too, if you'd like

}
```

However, you should probably only do this for `Copy` types, to avoid the users being surprised by hidden allocations.

For `Copy` types you'll likely need 4 impls to be able to add both values to references and references to values, as follows:

```
impl std::ops::Add<T> for T;
impl<'a> std::ops::Add<T> for &'a T;
impl<'a> std::ops::Add<&'a T> for T;
impl<'a, 'b> std::ops::Add<&'a T> for &'b T; // Not sure if two lifetimes are needed here, but shouldn't hurt
```

Comment: Worth noting that the standard library trait implementors https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html#implementors do implement e.g. for `i32` four times, once for each combination of referenceness.

Comment: I don't think the standard library implements it for references for non-`Copy` types, in order to avoid the hidden allocation. So I think maybe for `Copy` types it's worth doing all 4 impls, I'll add it to the answer

Comment: That makes sense, I don't personally care if something heap allocates under the hood, but I see why that wouldn't be desirable in some places. And I didn't even think about being able to implement a trait for its reference. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: _>You can always implement Add for references and .cloneing inside of them._

Could anyone explain why .clone-ing is mentioned here and why it would be necessary to clone when Add is implemented for a reference?

Comment: @anon2328 For non-`Copy` types, when implementing `Add<&T> for &T`, you have two `&T` to work with. But if you want to delegate the implementation to the `Add<T> for T` (or `Add<&T> for T`), you'll need to clone the `&T` to get a `T` to be able to call the other implementations.